# Multiple Markers crashing Browsers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am loading about 15,000 markers on the google map.

I have retrieved 1000 markers by using timeinterval per second.

when it is completed and 15000 markers are load on map then it crashes browser.

so, what i have to do for this issue.

Please do not vote down.

```
 for (x in dataObject) {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(dataObject[x].Latitude, dataObject[x].Longitude);
        var scaleSize = getSectorSize(dataObject[x].Mapinfo_Sector_Size);
        var sectorColor = getSectorColor(dataObject[x].Radios);
        var pathValue = createPie(dataObject[x].MapInfo_Beamwidth);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerPosition,
            map: map,
            icon: {
                path: pathValue,
                fillColor: sectorColor,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '',
                strokeWeight: 0,
                //scale: 0.8,
                scale: dataObject[x].Mapinfo_Sector_Size + 0.04,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                rotation: 250 + dataObject[x].Azimuth,
                //rotation: 250,
            },
        });
```

Comment: In chrome, open the developer tools, click timeline, check the box "capture memory", press the record button (top left) and reload your page. How much memory is being used?

Comment: 15,000 markers is a LOT, and I'm not surprised you got a crash!  Is there another way you can display this data?  For example, sample the data before displaying it so you show 1,000 markers that represent the same distribution of positions?

Comment: yes, i know 15000 markers is a lot. But, i have to find out the way to do that. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a google maps project myself and have seen performance issues when the number of markers increase beyond even 500.

google maps documentation itself provides a few valid [workarounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers), of which I have used [MarkerClusterer v3](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html) which provides a nice way of managing large number of markers. **However using MarkerClusterer will NOT improve your performance issues**.

If you still want display 15000 markers to users in a single viewport (which in itself is does not sound correct from the point of view of user experience) then you could take  a look at adding markers to overlays, this blog

[How To Quickly Add Many Markers Without Killing The Map](http://nickjohnson.com/b/google-maps-v3-how-to-quickly-add-many-markers)

provides a sound solution of adding an overlap (div) above the map and adding markers to the div. The blog also provides an example of loading 1000 markers. I am not sure if this will hold with 15000 :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey friend Thank you for your response. I have to try with this overlay.

Comment: The funny thing is that using Chrome (at least for me), the *slow* solution loads faster than the one described as *fast*. I guess this depends on a few parameters such as your hardware, OS, browser, etc.